# MVC send model to view without return view(model)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a website with just one view that contains several partial views. (tabs).

I want to send a object model(list) from my action to my view, but because im using just one view it interfere with the other model, so i cant send a model to the view. It is possible to return the model to just my partial view, where i want the model, but this ruins the whole website, (just displays the specific partial views and not others). The only other way i can think off is viewbag, but ive tried it and i did not behave like i wanted to.

The files im trying to pass to my view must have a high security. What other ways are there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use child actions; they were designed for this kind of thing:

**FooController.cs**

```
 [ChildActionOnly]
 public ActionResult GetListOfStuff()
 {
     // fetch listOfStuff
     return PartialView(listOfStuff);
 }
```

**Views/Foo/GetListOfStuff.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<Path.To.StuffModel>

@* HTML for displaying the list here *@
```

**Views\Foo\TheRealAction.cshtml**

```
@model Path.To.SomeOtherModel

...

@Html.Action("GetListOfStuff", "Foo")
```

Note: `ChildActionOnly` ensures that this action can only be called using `Html.Action` or `Html.RenderAction` (versus directly via a URL in the browser), so your data is as secure as the action calling it.

Answer (score 0):

You could chose to have them all inherit from the same `BaseViewModel` class, where some properties are left null, on pages that do not need that information. Without knowing more about the different kinds of models you want to send, it's hard to be more specific.

every action would then use:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = new BaseViewModel();
    return View(viewModel);
}
public ActionResult ShowList()
{
    var viewModel = new BaseViewModel
    {
        ListProp = new MyList()
    };
    return View(viewModel);
}
```